# Kentico Repeater showing a list of the recent page updates

Tags: kentico

This request came in, where Marketing would like a spot on the home page that shows the pages that have been updated. I'm thinking recent 5. I have a mix of page types, CMS.File, CMS.MenuItem, and a few custom page types. Does anyone have an example of something like this?

I was thinking a repeater, with my page types, top N at 5, and order by Publish Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that solution is exactly what you said. As orderby column you can use "DocumentModifiedWhen"

Comment: I've reduced the scope of this a bit to only show one page type. Thanks!